# How can I fix the issue of pdfs loading as blank pages in my React application with Typescript using pdfmake in production?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, pdfmake

I have a problem in my React application with Typescript using pdfmake.
In a dev environment it works perfectly showing the PDFs in the browser, but when I do a yarn run build of my application and upload it to production, the PDFs just load a blank page and don't show anything.

This is the information that is shown when I build the application:

[Message shown in application build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOSEP.png)

This is the component that assembles the PDF.

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
import * as pdfMake from 'pdfmake/build/pdfmake';
import * as pdfFonts from 'pdfmake/build/vfs_fonts';

(<any>pdfMake).vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;

import { DateTime } from 'luxon';
import _ from 'lodash';

import { ListCompaniesReportOptions } from './ReportsApi';

export default async function ListCompaniesReports(customersReports: ListCompaniesReportOptions[] | undefined) {
    const date = DateTime.local().toFormat('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
    const totalQuantity = _.sumBy(customersReports, 'quantidade_entregas');

    const taxa =
        customersReports && customersReports?.[0].qtdeEntrega <= totalQuantity
            ? customersReports?.[0].valor_entrega_pedido_maior
            : customersReports?.[0].valor_entrega_pedido_menor;

    const valorEntrega = customersReports && customersReports?.[0].valor_entregas - Number(taxa);

    const itemsCustomerReport = customersReports?.map?.((item) => {
        return [
            { text: item.fantasia, fontSize: 8, margin: [0, 3, 0, 3] },
            {
                text: DateTime.fromISO(item.createdAt).toFormat('dd/MM/yyyy'),
                fontSize: 8,
                margin: [0, 3, 0, 3],
            },
            {
                text: item.quantidade_entregas < 10 ? `0${item.quantidade_entregas}` : item.quantidade_entregas,
                fontSize: 8,
                margin: [0, 3, 0, 3],
                alignment: 'left',
            },
            {
                text: '',
                fontSize: 8,
                margin: [0, 3, 0, 3],
                alignment: 'left',
            },
        ];
    });

    // pdfMake.vfs = pdfFonts.pdfMake.vfs;
    const reportTitle = [
        {
            text: 'RELATÓRIO DAS ENTREGAS REALIZADAS NA ÚLTIMA SEMANA',
            style: 'header',
            alignment: 'center',
            margin: [0, -20, 0, 20],
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 14,
        },
        {
            text: customersReports?.[0].nome,
            style: 'header',
            alignment: 'center',
            margin: [0, -10, 0, 10],
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 10,
        },
    ];

    const reportTable = [
        {
            style: 'tableExample',
            table: {
                headerRows: 1,
                widths: [150, '*', '*', '*'],
                body: [
                    [
                        { text: 'CLIENTE', style: 'tableHeader', fontSize: 8 },
                        { text: 'DATA', style: 'tableHeader', fontSize: 8 },
                        { text: 'Q.ENTREGAS', style: 'tableHeader', fontSize: 8 },
                        { text: '', style: 'tableHeader', fontSize: 8 },
                    ],
                    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
                    // @ts-ignore
                    ...itemsCustomerReport,
                    [
                        { text: 'TOTAIS', style: 'tableHeader', fontSize: 8, bold: true, margin: [0, 10, 0, 0] },
                        { text: '', style: 'tableHeader', fontSize: 8 },
                        {
                            text: `${totalQuantity} X ${Number(valorEntrega).toLocaleString('pt-br', {
                                style: 'currency',
                                currency: 'BRL',
                            })}`,
                            alignment: 'left',
                            style: 'tableHeader',
                            fontSize: 8,
                            bold: true,
                            margin: [0, 10, 0, 0],
                        },
                        {
                            text: (totalQuantity * Number(valorEntrega)).toLocaleString('pt-br', {
                                style: 'currency',
                                currency: 'BRL',
                            }),
                            alignment: 'left',
                            style: 'tableHeader',
                            fontSize: 8,
                            bold: true,
                            margin: [0, 10, 0, 0],
                        },
                    ],
                ],
            },
            layout: 'lightHorizontalLines',
        },
    ];

    const reportDefinitions = {
        pageSize: 'A4',
        pageMargins: [40, 60, 40, 60],
        content: [
            ...reportTitle,
            ...reportTable,
            {
                text: date,
                alignment: 'right',
                margin: [0, 21, 0, 0],
                absolutePosition: { x: 0, y: 15 },
                fontSize: 8,
            },
            {
                text: 'Copyright © 2023 - Todos os direitos reservados - Desenvolvido por Connect Software',
                alignment: 'right',
                margin: [0, 0, 5, 0],
                fontSize: 7,
                absolutePosition: { x: 0, y: 8 },
            },
        ],
    };

    // @ts-ignore
    pdfMake.createPdf(reportDefinitions).open();
}
```

I've tried a few things I found on forums, but to no avail. I tried to update the Vite version but also without success.
I tried to change the form of font imports, but without success.